# Select Promotional Price

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

### The goal

Get the lowest price of a product.

### The problem

To illustrate my problem:

> **Row 1**
>
> - `Product_Id` = 1
> - `Product_Name` = "iPhone 5"
> - `Market_Name` = "Walmart"
> - `Product_Original_Price` = "359.00"
> - `Product_Promotional_Price` = "319.00"
> - `Product_State` = 1 (is on offer)
>
> **Row 2**
>
> - `Product_Id` = 1
> - `Product_Name` = "iPhone 5"
> - `Market_Name` = "Apple"
> - `Product_Original_Price` = "359.00"
> - `Product_Promotional_Price` = "0.00"
> - `Product_State` = 0 (isn't on offer)
>
> **Row 3**
>
> - `Product_Id` = 1
> - `Product_Name` = "iPhone 5"
> - `Market_Name` = "BestBuy"
> - `Product_Original_Price` = "359.00"
> - `Product_Promotional_Price` = "299.00"
> - `Product_State` = 1 (is on offer)

The query of the next topic (***What I have***) is returning me zero as the best price of the problem illustrated above — but the best price is `299.00`, by `BestBuy`, because zero at `Product_Promotional_Price` means that the product isn't on offer.

### What I have

```
SELECT
  MIN(LEAST(`Product_Original_Price`, `Product_Promotional_Price`)) as `minProductPrice`
[...]
```

### Details

My query:

```
    SELECT  `pr`.`Product_Id` as `productId`,
    `pr`.`Product_Name` as `productName`,
    ROUND(CAST(MIN(`map`.`Product_Original_Price`) AS DECIMAL)/100,2) 
      as `minProductPrice`,
    `prm`.`Product_Measure_Name` as `measureName`,
    `prm`.`Product_Measure_Shortname` as `measureShortName`,
    `pri`.`Product_Thumbnail_Image_Url` as `thumbnailUrl`,
    `pr`.`Product_Markets_Quantity` as `numberOfMarketsThatHaveThisProduct`
FROM `bm_market_products` as `map`
JOIN `bm_products` as `pr` ON `map`.`Product_Id` = `pr`.`Product_Id`
JOIN `bm_products_category_relationship` as `car` ON `pr`.`Product_Id` =
      `car`.`Product_Id`
JOIN `bm_product_categories` as `ca` ON `car`.`Category_Id` = `ca`.`Category_Id`
JOIN `bm_products_measure_relationship` as `prmr` ON `pr`.`Product_Id` = 
      `prmr`.`Product_Id`
JOIN `bm_product_measures` as `prm` ON `prmr`.`Measure_Id` =
      `prm`.`Product_Measure_Id`
JOIN `bm_products_images` as `pri` ON `pr`.`Product_Id` = `pri`.`Product_Id`
WHERE ("" IS NULL OR `map`.`Product_State` = 0)
AND ("" IS NULL OR `ca`.`Category_Id` = 14)
GROUP BY `map`.`Product_Id`;
```

What the query returns:

[image: SQL Result]

### What I already have tried:

Considering that `Product_State` determines whether a product is on offer or not, follow this fragment:

```
SELECT  `pr`.`Product_Id` as `productId`,
    `pr`.`Product_Name` as `productName`,
    (IF(`map`.`Product_State` <> 0) THEN
      MIN(LEAST(`Product_Original_Price`, `Product_Promotional_Price`))
    ELSE (`map`.Product_Original_Price) as `minProductPrice`,
    `prm`.`Product_Measure_Name` as `measureName`,
    `prm`.`Product_Measure_Shortname` as `measureShortName`,
    `pri`.`Product_Thumbnail_Image_Url` as `thumbnailUrl`,
    `pr`.`Product_Markets_Quantity` as `numberOfMarketsThatHaveThisProduct`
[...]
```

Can you see the ***IF/THEN/ELSE***? This is what has been added in relation to the previous query.

The above query doesn't work — syntax isn't correct, I know, but it was just to illustrate.

### The solution

[Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176997/2231918) and with it, I made this:

```
SELECT  [...]
    ROUND(CAST(MIN(CASE WHEN `map`.`Product_Promotional_Price` = 0 THEN `map`.`Product_Original_Price`
            ELSE LEAST(`map`.`Product_Promotional_Price`, `map`.`Product_Original_Price`)
       end) AS DECIMAL)/100,2) as `minProductPrice`,
        [...]
```

To clarify, I just adapted his [Gordon Linoff] syntax to my scenario — with [`ROUND`](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-round-numbers/) to rounding numbers and [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) to set a value as a certain type.

**Worked perfectly!!** Thanks!!

Comment: Kudos for a well written and detailed question

Comment: +1 for using bold large letters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix your logic for getting the lowest price.  A case statement is the best way.  Here is an example:

```
select MIN(case when `Product_Promotional_Price` = 0 then `Product_Original_Price`
                else least(`Product_Promotional_Price`, `Product_Original_Price`)
           end)
```

Answer (score 0):

put `where Product_Original_Price!=0 and Product_Promotional_Price!=0` to the end;